# Can't serve jupyter notebook with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: python-2.7, nginx, jupyter-notebook

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a jupyter notebook running localhost on a VM and serve it online using nginx reverse proxy over https.

For the moment I am trying to serve it over plain http to test that it works

I used many configurations that I found online but it is not working.

My nginx configuration for the moment goes like this:

```
server{
   listen 80;
   server_name jupyterdomain.com;

   location /home/user/.jupyter {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_read_timeout 86400;
   }
}
```

Then I used the jupyter notebook password to create a password, which generated a JSON file with the hash key, which I copied into the jupyter_notebook_config.py file

In the jupyter_notebook_config.py file I have the following configurations:

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.NotebookApp.allow_root = False
c.NotebookApp.base_url = 'jupyterdomain.com'
c.NotebookApp.ip = '127.0.0.1'
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'/home/user/.jupyter'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:passwordhash'
c.NotebookApp.password_required = True
c.NotebookApp.port = port
c.NotebookApp.port_retries = 50
```

When starting jupyter notebook it seems to be running fine with the following message:

```
[I 15:35:22.626 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user/.jupyter
[I 15:35:22.626 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 15:35:22.626 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:35:22.626 NotebookApp] http://127.0.0.1:port/jupyterdomain.com/
[I 15:35:22.627 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

So the problem is that jupyterdomain.com serves the nginx welcome page.

I don't know what I am missing, it could be a nginx configuration or jupyter configuration. Maybe I didn't install jupyter properly? Like wrong path or something.

Note that I didn't use anacoda, I only used pip and python 2.7 ( which is the version that I want jupyter to run on)

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

EDIT: Trying to access notebook from my local pc via ssh tunneling is successfull but only using:

"localhost:port/jupyterdomain.com" on the browser.

Not on localhost:port

Answer (score 0):

Try the configuration here, or a variant thereof:
http://nathan.vertile.com/blog/2017/12/07/run-jupyter-notebook-behind-a-nginx-reverse-proxy-subpath/

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ngix or apache, but I have code to put jupyter behind haproxy and works very well:

```
backend jupyter
        option forwardfor
        http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src]
        reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /mez/(.*) \1\ /\2
        reqadd X-Script-Name:\ /<WEBSITENAME>
        option http-server-close
        server Server12 10.0.0.12:8888 weight 40 check
        server Server14 10.0.0.14:8888 weight 20 check
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my set up .
it is supposed that http://abc/jupyter will redirect to
http://localhost:8888/jupyter

Step 1 : setup jupyter notebook (jupyter_notebook_config.py)
c.NotebookApp.base_project_url = '/jupyter/'

Then nginx

```
  location /jupyter  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_read_timeout 20d;
  }
```